# how to create jquery plugin for Speedometer

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have working as web developer and create tiny jquery plugin such as reverse text,slider image. Now i want to create speedometer. I haven't any idea how to start to create speedometer plugin. I have also googling but do not get any fine solution.

Comment: not hard to find gauge like charts ... keep searching. This question is far too broad for SO

Comment: http://harmoniccode.blogspot.in/2011/04/steelseries-javascript-edition.html try this..

Answer (score 1):

You will find a usefull tutorial for creating a Dynamic speedometer with jquery and CSS3 [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Creating-An-Animated-Speedometer-with-jQuery-CSS3.html), this is a jQuery plugin helps you create an animated & highly customizable speedometer representing the number you type into an input field. Based on jQuery and CSS3 transitions & transforms. No image needed.

how to use:

```
$("#demo").myfunc({
    maxVal  : 180, // Max value of the meter
    divFact : 10,  // Division value of the meter
    dangerLevel : 120, // more than this leval, color will be red
    initDeg : -45, // reading begins angle
    maxDeg  : 270, // total angle of the meter reading
    edgeRadius  : 150, // radius of the meter circle
    speedNobeH  : 4,   // speed nobe height
    speedoNobeW : 95,  // speed nobe width
    speedoNobeL : 13,  // speed nobe left position
    indicatorRadius : 125, // radius of indicators position
    indicatorNumbRadius : 90,  // radius of numbers position
    speedPositionTxtWH  : 80,  // speedo-meter current value cont
    nobW: 20,  // indicator nob width
    nobH: 4,   // indicator nob height
    numbW   : 30,  // indicator number width
    numbH   : 16,  // indicator number height
    midNobW : 10,  // indicator mid nob width
    midNobH : 3,   // indicator mid nob height
    noOfSmallDiv: 2,   // no of small div between main div
    eventListenerType   : 'change',// no of small div between main div
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply @xzegga, but i can't find download link for speedometer.css and speedometer.js

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/download/Creating-An-Animated-Speedometer-with-jQuery-CSS3.zip

Comment: there are a blue buton to download the script on top of the page under the title

Comment: If this answer respond to your question feel free to mark as right answer :)